# How to split one row into multiple rows in a generic way in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
name           text       group
a|b            a test     m|l|n
```

I have a DataFrame like above. If there is a delimiter in a column value, I want to split it and put it in a separate line.

```
columns = ['name', 'text', 'group']            
for column in columns:
   if column == 'name' and column in df:
      df = df.assign(name=df.name.str.split(delimiter)).explode(column)
```

The problem with this code is that, I have to use multiple if to test the actual column name string, i.e. 'name'. I want to a general way like below:

```
if column in df:
   df = df.assign(column=df.column.str.split(delimiter)).explode(column)
```

But this is invalid. Any walk-around to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[]` instead dot notation:

```
delimiter = '|'
column = 'group'

if column in df:
    df = df.assign(**{column:df[column].str.split(delimiter)}).explode(column)
    print (df)
  name    text group
0  a|b  a test     m
0  a|b  a test     l
0  a|b  a test     n
```

Another idea if need exploding multiple columns:

```
#get values from columns list if exist in df.columns
cols = df.columns.intersection(columns)         
print (cols)

#assign back splitted columns by dict comprehension and explode by all columns in list cols
df = df.assign(**{x: df[x].str.split(delimiter) for x in cols}).explode(cols)
```

Comment: Let me try it! If the first way works, that would be simplest.

Comment: But I got this error message after I made the change: df = df.assign(column=df[column].str.split(delimiter)).explode(column) TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @marlon - Problem is use old pandas version, is possible upgrade to last?

Comment: Yes, I will try.

Comment: So that requires python3.8, right? I am using Python3.7 and will upgrade it first. Also, would your second way of exploding multiple columns be more efficient? The first method is quite slow when I have a lot of columns that need to be split.

Comment: @marlon - In my opinion it should be slowier :(

Comment: I upgraded to latest Pandas, but it complain the same error. What may be the cause?  Jezrael?

Comment: @marlon - tested and you are right, need dictionary. answer was edited.